Splash Screen is not showing ionic vue capacitor
I am experiencing an issue with the splash screen not displaying in my Ionic Vue project using Capacitor. Despite following the standard setup instructions, the splash screen does not appear when the app is launched.

The splash screen is not showing up at all when the app is started.
I have verified that the necessary plugins are installed and configured according to the - Ionic documentation.
I have tried various troubleshooting steps, including clearing the build cache, reinstalling dependencies, and double-checking the configuration in capacitor.config.ts.

import { Capacitor } from '@capacitor/core';

const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  appId: 'com.example.app',
  appName: 'MyApp',
  webDir: 'dist',
  bundledWebRuntime: false,
  plugins: {
    SplashScreen: {
      launchShowDuration: 3000,
      launchAutoHide: true,
      backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
      androidSplashResourceName: 'splash',
      androidScaleType: 'CENTER_CROP',
      showSpinner: true,
      androidSpinnerStyle: 'large',
      iosSpinnerStyle: 'small',
      spinnerColor: '#999999',
      splashFullScreen: true,
      splashImmersive: true,
    },
  },
};

export default config;

launch_screen.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/splash">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/splash" />
</RelativeLayout>

styles.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:background">@null</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Define AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch -->
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Corrected SplashTheme definition -->
    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch">
        <item name="android:background">@layout/launch_screen</item>
    </style>

</resources>

activity_main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

androidmanifest.xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode" android:exported="true" android:label="@string/title_activity_main" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:name=".MainActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>


You need to follow the following steps:
1- Check the generated resources for the splash screen.
2- Connect to a device and check the ://inspect from you browser like chrome://inspect
3- Check if there's any extra configuration for the splash screen in native files(android and ios folder).
It's working with me and I never face this issue before, I am using     "@capacitor/splash-screen": "^4.0.0",
Maybe if you can give more information about the issue after debugging or what's the behaviour of the application on real device.
Goodluck, I hope it works, let me know!

Please check the code I have added from the other file. I am still not able to see the splash screen, even though I tried using @capacitor/splash-screen: "^4.0.0".
